# JSON Schema Validation Conditional

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

So I have this schema and I am trying to validate it but also include conditionals. I found some previously asked questions and followed the provided answers, however I couldn't get my schema to validate properly.

I followed the answer from this post: [Stack Overflow JSON Schema Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928079/json-schema-conditional-statements) but it's not working

Here is my schema. Basically it's supposed to require certain fields based on `commodityType` but it's not working and schema validators are throwing all sorts of errors. Am not sure what I am doing wrong...

I should also add that I am using npm jsonschema to work with the schemas...

```
  {
  "$id": "/commodity",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Commodity Schema",
  "description": "Element of the Commodities Array",
  "examples": [
    {
      "commodityType": "Vehicles",
      "deliveryStopNumber": 1,
      "description": "Describes Freight (not used for vehicle commodities",
      "isInoperable": true,
      "length": 30,
      "make": "MAZDA",
      "model": "CX-7",
      "quantity": 3,
      "tariff": 260.34,
      "vehicleType": "SUV",
      "vin": "JM3ER29L670150717",
      "weight": 3331,
      "year": "2007"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "commodityType": {
      "$id": "#/properties/commodityType",
      "type": ["string"],
      "title": "Commodity Type",
      "description": "Enum: Vehicles, Crushed Cars, Pallets, Bulk",
      "examples": ["Vehicles"],
      "enum": ["Vehicles", "Crushed Cars", "Pallets", "Bulk"]
    },
    "deliveryStopNumber": {
      "$id": "#/properties/deliveryStopNumber",
      "type": ["integer"],
      "title": "Delivery Stop Number",
      "description": "At which stop will this commodity be dropped off (ONLY used for multi drop orders)",
      "examples": [1],
      "default": 1
    },
    "description": {
      "$id": "#/properties/description",
      "type": ["string", "null"],
      "title": "Describes the Commodity",
      "description": "Freight Description (set to null for Vehicle commodities)",
      "examples": ["Heavy Tables"],
      "default": null
    },
    "isInoperable": {
      "$id": "#/properties/isInoperable",
      "type": ["boolean", "null"],
      "title": "Is Vehicle Inoperable",
      "description": "(Used for Vehicle commodities Only)",
      "examples": [true, false, null],
      "default": false,
      "enum": [true, false, null]
    },
    "length": {
      "$id": "#/properties/length",
      "type": ["integer", "null"],
      "title": "Length of Freight in Feet",
      "description": "(set to null for Vehicle commodities)",
      "examples": [30],
      "default": null
    },
    "make": {
      "$id": "#/properties/make",
      "type": ["string", "null"],
      "title": "Vehicle Make",
      "description": "",
      "examples": ["MAZDA"]
    },
    "model": {
      "$id": "#/properties/model",
      "type": ["string", "null"],
      "title": "Vehicle Model",
      "description": "",
      "examples": ["CX-7"]
    },
    "pickupStopNumber": {
      "$id": "#/properties/pickupStopNumber",
      "type": ["integer", "null"],
      "title": "Pickup Stop Number",
      "description": "At which stop will this commodity be picked up (only used for multi drop orders)",
      "examples": [1],
      "default": 0
    },
    "quantity": {
      "$id": "#/properties/quantity",
      "type": ["integer", "null"],
      "title": "Quantity of this item",
      "description": "i.e. Amount of Pallets (used for non-Vehicle commodities)",
      "examples": [5],
      "default": 0
    },
    "tariff": {
      "$id": "#/properties/tariff",
      "type": "number",
      "title": "Tariff",
      "description": "Amount Being Payed To RCG For This Commodity",
      "default": 0,
      "examples": [260.23]
    },
    "vehicleType": {
      "$id": "#/properties/vehicleType",
      "type": ["string"],
      "title": "Vehicle Type",
      "description": "Describes Vehicle (use Picklist)",
      "examples": ["JM3ER29L670150717"],
      "enum": [
        "Sedan",
        "Coupe",
        "Convertible",
        "SUV",
        "Minivan",
        "Pickup Truck (2 Door)",
        "Pickup Truck (4 Door)",
        "Motorcycle",
        "ATV",
        "Boat",
        "RV",
        "Trailer (5th Wheel)",
        "Trailer (Bumper Pull)",
        "Trailer (Gooseneck)",
        "Cargo Van",
        "Box Truck",
        "Pickup Dually",
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    "vin": {
      "$id": "#/properties/vin",
      "type": ["string", "null"],
      "title": "VIN",
      "description": "Vehicle Identification Number",
      "examples": ["JM3ER29L670150717"]
    },
    "weight": {
      "$id": "#/properties/weight",
      "type": ["number", "null"],
      "title": "Weight In Pounds",
      "description": "Weight of commodity (used for non-Vehicle commodities)",
      "examples": [3000],
      "default": null
    },
    "year": {
      "$id": "#/properties/year",
      "type": ["string", "null"],
      "title": "The year schema",
      "description": "Vehicle Year",
      "examples": ["2007"],
      "default": null
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "commodityType",
    "deliveryStopNumber",
    "pickupStopNumber",
    "tariff"
  ],
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "if": { "properties": { "commodityType": { "const": "Vehicles" } } },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "commodityType",
          "deliveryStopNumber",
          "isInoperable",
          "make",
          "model",
          "pickupStopNumber",
          "tariff",
          "vehicleType",
          "vin",
          "year"
        ]
      },
      "else": false
    },
    {
      "if": { "properties": { "commodityType": { "const": "Pallets" } } },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "commodityType",
          "deliveryStopNumber",
          "description",
          "length",
          "pickupStopNumber",
          "quantity",
          "tariff",
          "weight"
        ]
      },
      "else": false
    },
    {
      "if": { "properties": { "commodityType": { "const": "Crushed Cars" } } },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "commodityType",
          "deliveryStopNumber",
          "description",
          "length",
          "pickupStopNumber",
          "quantity",
          "tariff",
          "weight"
        ]
      },
      "else": false
    },
    {
      "if": { "properties": { "commodityType": { "const": "Bulk" } } },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "commodityType",
          "deliveryStopNumber",
          "description",
          "length",
          "pickupStopNumber",
          "quantity",
          "tariff",
          "weight"
        ]
      },
      "else": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Relequestual I followed your example from the post, but it seems to be full of errors.

Comment: Could you show the errors that you are getting? That would be the first clue.

Comment: The error is that none of the fields in the required arrays from the conditionals are even checked. i.e I can have make, model, and description, it doesn't throw any errors whatsoever. @Ether

Comment: "it's not working and schema validators are throwing all sorts of errors" -- what errors?

Comment: @Ether well I tried using if then else and thats when it would tell me that property A is required and the next error would be property A is not allowed (extra field). Then when I switched to using anyOf it stopped validating everything in the anyOf scope. Extra fields or missing fields, it all gets ignored.. Properties getting ignored are the errors I am referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `anyOf` to `allOf`, and drop all the `else: false` clauses, which will at least make the errors (when they are emitted) more helpful.

Also, if/then/else weren't introduced until draft version 7, so if you are using an evaluator that doesn't support that version, those keywords will be ignored entirely.

Comment: Yeah your comment regarding the draft versions helped me figure out that I needed to use a different npm package and then all of my issues were fixed. For Anyone Looking at this comment I went with `ajv`.

Answer (score 0):

In places where you have something like, `"type": ["integer", null],`, it should be `"type": ["integer", "null"],`. `type` takes an array of strings. It doesn't work because `null` is not a string.

Comment: Putting the the null into quotes didn't fix the conditionals.

Comment: That was the only syntax error. If something else isn't working, you'll need to be more specific about the problem you are having.

Comment: Right. The conditionals in the anyOf array don't work. What I mean by that is that I can have a make and weight in the same object and I don't get any errors.  From the schema you can see that make is supposed to occur when commodityType is vehicle... however that entire conditional seems to be ignored..

Comment: I was going to edit my answer, but @Ether's answer is correct, so I won't bother to repeat her answer.